# Iterate over arrays in Julia

Tags: julia

This is the function I want to use. I am trying to use temperature data & precipiation data of a whole week. This means the arguments: `temp` & `precip`, will be an array of length 7. How do i make this work?

```
function humidityindex(temp, precip)
    moist_effect = 0
    temp_effect = 0 
    for i in 1:size(precip)
        moist_effect += ((precip[i]/100) * (1-(i/10)))
        temp_effect -= ((temp[i]/25) * (1-(i/10)))
    end

    effect = temp_effect + moist_effect
    return effect 
end
```

The function results in the following `MethodError`:

```
julia> t = rand(7); p = rand(7);

julia> humidityindex(t, p)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching (::Colon)(::Int64, ::Tuple{Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  Any(::T, ::Any, ::T) where T<:Real at range.jl:41
  Any(::A, ::Any, ::C) where {A<:Real, C<:Real} at range.jl:10
  Any(::T, ::Any, ::T) where T at range.jl:40
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] humidityindex(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at ./REPL[1]:4
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[3]:1
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly your problem is? At first glance there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code, but of course it depends on how exactly `temp` and `precip` are defined. Can you add these to your example and show how the ouptut of the function differs from what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for editing - this is exactly the issue Fredrik anticipated below (`size()` returns a tuple of dimensions, so you are trying to create a range `1:(7, )` rather than the range `1:7`)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is how you create the iteration space: `for i in 1:size(precip)`. `size` in Julia returns a tuple. You want to use `length` instead (or `size(precip, 1)` for the size in the first dimension).

```
function humidityindex(temp, precip)
    moist_effect = 0
    temp_effect = 0 
    for i in 1:length(precip)       # <--   Updated this line
        moist_effect += ((precip[i]/100) * (1-(i/10)))
        temp_effect -= ((temp[i]/25) * (1-(i/10)))
    end

    effect = temp_effect + moist_effect
    return effect 
end
```

Comment: Or `eachindex(temp, precip)` instead of the whole range.

Comment: Yea, that also makes sure the length of the both arrays matches.

Answer (score 6):

The answer given by the first Fredrik is the answer to your question. This is simply a short and efficient way of calculating the same thing.

```
moist_effect((i,x)) = (x/100) * (1-(i/10))
temp_effect((i,x)) = -(x/25) * (1-(i/10))
function humidityindex(temp, precip)
    sum(moist_effect, enumerate(precip)) + sum(temp_effect, enumerate(temp))
end
```

Notice the *tuple destructuring* in `moist_effect((i,x))`, I added this since `enumerate` iterates tuples of indices and values.

The function `sum` has a method that accepts a function as its first argument. This method applies that function to all elements before summing them up.